# Escape double quotes in command parameter

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to run a PS command on SQL Server. Running a simple command without double-quotes works without a problem.

How to run below command?

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);
 SET @sql = 
 '
 powershell.exe -command "
 $messageBody = "ds"
 Write-Host $messageBody
 "';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

I tried this ` and backslash but nothing seems to be working.

Running it from ps1 file is **not** an option.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` has serious security implications, and is difficult to use. Why do you *have* to call PS from SQL Server? And have you considered creating a SQL Server Agent job written in PS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `"ds"`, use `''ds''` to use single quotes withing the ps script to enclose the literal. Furthermore, use the call operator (&) withing the [command parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-command) to call the script block:

```
SET @sql = 'powershell.exe -command "& { $messageBody = ''ds''; Write-Host $messageBody }';
```

Comment: How would you do a line break when ` doesn't work?

Comment: @sixplus4iszen, I don't think one can specify multi-line commands via `xp_cmdshell`. Using `xp_cmdhsell` in general is a dubious practice and disallowed in most organizations. There are usually better ways to accomplish the desired result than via T-SQL.